# design class to parse different version of binary file with c++

Tags: c++, version, binaryfiles

I want to parse some binary file.  we can say that the file only contains file_header and file_content.  we use YFileHeader and YfileContent to represent it.

For the whole binary file,  I used YFile to represent it.

I just care about the flag1 and flag2 in YFileHeader.  which will be used in YFile to do some complex things.

```
class YFileHeader {
    private:
        int flag1;
        int flag2;
    public:
        int getF1() { return flag1; }
        int getF2() { return flag2; }
};

class YfileContent {
    public:
        int len;
        char* c;
};

class YFile {
    private:
        YFileHeader h;
        YFileContent c;
    public:
        int getF1() { return h.getF1(); }
        int getF2() { return h.getF2(); }
        int yf {
            /*
             * do some complex things with getF1() and getF2()
             */
            return getF1() + getF2();
        }
        char* getContent() { return c.c; }
};

/*
 *  YFile* yFile = (YFile*) mmap(....);
 *  yFile->yf();
 *  yFile->getContent();
 */
```

But file version changed which caused the layout of file Header changed, the rest
 not

```
class YFileHeader_v2 {
    private:
        int flag1;
        int foo;
        int flag2;
    public:
        int getF1() { return flag1; }
        int getF2() { return flag2; }
};
```

How to design YFileHeader and YFile?  I think the difficulty are:
1. The length of YFileHeader may be changed.
2. We can't use Base class which contains some virtual methods only. since if so, any derived class will have a vpt members added.

Comment: This is why textual formats like [JSON](http://json.org/) are in practice very useful.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch,  how can you know I asked this question?  I went to http://stackoverflow.com/tags, and  checked both c++ and binaryfiles tags, I couldn't find out my question there.